# C# access specified sub array

Tags: c#, arrays

My data file which contains an array of double numbers (these are offsets from the center line of a road and its spot heights in meters) every group was leaded by a center line increasing every 20 m :

10250.000

-100.00 660.698
-050.00 665.789
-025.00 667.269
0.00 664.101
025.00 666.225
050.00 668.987
100.00 664.361

10270.000

-100.00 667.772
-050.00 663.907
-025.00 668.065
0.00 668.101
025.00 667.225
050.00 665.899
100.00 663.365

10290.000

-100.00 663.698
-050.00 665.989
-025.00 676.999
0.00 665.105
025.00 676.225
050.00 677.797
100.00 665.371
.
.
.

10330.000

-100.00 665.594
-050.00 662.985
-025.00 667.762
0.00 667.106
025.00 667.823
050.00 668.087
100.00 669.357

I want to write a C# program, that can read and access specified center line number and its sub array offsets & spot heights.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please post your relevant code and what is the specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new CenterLine(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class CenterLine
    {
        public static List<CenterLine> centerLines = new List<CenterLine>();

        public double centerLine { get; set; }
        public List<double> heights { get; set; }

        enum State
        {
            GET_CENTER_LINE,
            GET_HEIGHTS
        }
        public CenterLine() { }
        public CenterLine(string filename)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);

            string inputLine = "";

            State state = State.GET_CENTER_LINE;

            CenterLine newCenterLine = null;
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (inputLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case State.GET_CENTER_LINE :
                            newCenterLine = new CenterLine();
                            centerLines.Add(newCenterLine);
                            newCenterLine.centerLine = double.Parse(inputLine);

                            state = State.GET_HEIGHTS;
                            break;

                        case State.GET_HEIGHTS :
                            newCenterLine.heights = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                .Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToList();
                            state = State.GET_CENTER_LINE;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```